# Does the act of neural-repair fire off neurons?

Tags: neuro-transmitters

*Disclaimer: I'm not well educated in this field, just a random curious person.  I don't know anything about neural repair save that it happens while we sleep.*

Anyways, the question is pretty simple: **Does neural repair result in firing neurons?**

Perhaps a damaged neuron being healed sometimes misfires, perhaps the little road workers that go around fixing neurons sometimes bump into things nearby and knock something loose, perhaps the processes of repairing leaves a bunch of neuro transmitters just floating in that area.. any of these could be a *reason for **yes***.

A *reason for **no*** might be "We've studied where brain repair occurs, and where neurons are firing and there is no relation."

Any solid speculation is nice too, as long as it's offered with a grain of salt.

I'm really just looking for something better than "no clue."

Comment: What do you mean with repair leading to firing neurons? Are you referring to whether a repaired neuron retains the ability to fire action potentials? And what do you mean with neural repair in the first place? All cells undergo processes of repair, one way or another. Why would a 'repaired' neuron *not* fire?

Comment: During brain repair, does any aspect of that process cause impetus for a semi-random-firing.  As in, from my knowledge, most neurons get fired by something in the chain before.  But can they be fired by the process of healing?  Whether that be the helper cells which aid in their healing, or their own internal healing process, can the act of healing cause firing?  I am not asking about after healing or before, but during.  I am also not asking about it's ability to work normally, but instead about situational ways in which firing happens while the brain is healing some damaged aspect of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: Does neural repair result in firing neurons?

This is a difficult question. Because a repair occurs when and where there is a damage. If there are abnormal firings of neurons, it will be difficult to sort out which one is the cause. It is also possible that both cause the firings.

However, there is no evidence that the majority of repairs, which are the repairs to maintain healthy cellular structure and functions and which occur ubiquitously all the time in the nervous system in the normal condition, cause abnormal neuronal firings. For example, there is no evidence that abnormal brain waves, seizure activities, or abnormal neurological symptoms occurr in normal people because of these normal repairs.

So, all that can be concluded for now is that the majority of repairs, which occur in the normal condition, do not cause abnormal neuronal firings.

For more, please refer to:

Martino, G., Pluchino, S., Bonfanti, L., & Schwartz, M. (2011). Brain regeneration in physiology and pathology: the immune signature driving therapeutic plasticity of neural stem cells. *Physiological reviews, 91*(4), 1281-1304. doi: [10.1152/physrev.00032.2010](https://doi.org/10.1152/physrev.00032.2010) pcmcid: [PMC3552310](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3552310)

Comment: Thank you.  Would you mind giving me some keywords for the "ubiquitous" and more sleep centered healing types?  I'd like to dig into the sleep ones in particular.

Comment: Ubiquitous just means occurring everywhere. I don't have references on sleep-centered healing, just have some on general healing. This one may be useful to you [BRAIN REGENERATION IN PHYSIOLOGY AND PATHOLOGY](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3552310/). From there you can search more literature from its references, or you can google search with the key words like “normal physiologic brain neuron repair”.

Comment: There are no direct references. But there has never been a case report in the medical literature or medical textbooks of abnormal brain waves, seizure activities, or abnormal neurological symptoms that result from abnormal firing neurons from normal repairing in normal people. (Btw, I'm a neurologist who has been practicing for 35 years.)

Comment: do you mind explaining the mechanism of individual neuron repairing. I am just curious that according to what you said I have search “normal physiologic brain neuron repairing”. But the result I have got are mostly associated with either neurogenesis in the hippocampus and the plasticity of neurons. I’m wondering that how would a damages neuron (for example the damage in soma’s membrane) be able to repair itself. Or does the repairing process required glial cells? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4755395/

Comment: I’m not a physiologist and cannot explain the mechanism of individual neuron repairing myself. But  I think this reference [BRAIN REGENERATION IN PHYSIOLOGY AND PATHOLOGY](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3552310/) can help explain the mechanism.